# Redux-becon trackeCommProduct not firing a collect request[redux-beacon]

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-beacon

The following code produces a valid event in the redux-beacon logs. I can see the object getting created appropriately and the code being executed.

I have my analytics set up at a global level to support e-commerce:

`ga('create', window.gaKey, 'auto');
ga('require', 'ec');`

However, no collect request is actually being fired to GA. I'm having the same problem with trackEcommAction.

All trackEvent collections are going through correctly. What the heck?

```
case BookingActions.TRACK_BOOK_NOW_ECOMM_PRODUCT:
  return trackEcommProduct((eAction, ePrevState) => {
    const {
      confirmation_token,
      pricing,
      promotion,
    } = eAction.payload;
    const { total } = pricing;
    return {
      category: 'create-reservation',
      coupon: promotion,
      id: confirmation_token,
      name: ePrevState.bookingReducer.activeBooking.pickupLocation.multi_car_display_name,
      price: total,
      quantity: 1,
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Redux Beacon's Google Analytics Target, and is fixed in the latest version (`1.0.2`):

```
npm install @redux-beacon/google-analytics@1.0.2
```

See here for a more in-depth discussion:

https://github.com/rangle/redux-beacon/issues/254